# Can the many worlds interpretation use the Born rule for decoherence?

Tags: quantum-interpretations, decoherence, born-rule

[If the Many-Worlds Interpretation cannot derive the Born rule does it need mind body dualism to make sense of probabilities?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/433590/)

I asked a different question here regarding MWI and circularity. But here's something else that was thinking about. Does it logically make sense that the MWI uses the Born rule for decoherence (without deriving it). For example, in an experiment, the worlds decohere/split in accordance to the Born rule.

Comment: The Born rule is named after Max Born, and it is therefore *always* capitalized.

Comment: What would it mean to "use the Born rule for decoherence?" Decoherence is predicted by standard quantum mechanics, i.e., by the axioms that everyone agrees on regardless of whether they add the additional axioms that are needed in the Copenhagen interpretation. The Born rule is one of those additional axioms.

Comment: @BruceGreetham But the frequency operator with infinite trials has shown to be circular https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0409144 .

Comment: @BruceGreetham I'm sorry about my attitude.

Comment: Related questions by OP: [If the Many-Worlds Interpretation cannot derive the Born rule does it need mind body dualism to make sense of probabilities?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/433590) (closed, then deleted by OP), [How does the Many Worlds Interpretation define probability?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429946/) (closed), [Can the Many Worlds interpretation state the born rule as a postulate, while maintaining a logical coherent interpretation of probability?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/435334) (deleted by OP shortly before it was closed).